# Datastructure for Peg Board Game

Tags: data-structures

What datastructure would work for the triangular peg board game?

It's a 5x5x5 triangle with 15 holes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A boolean array of length 15.

Then I'd use either an adjacency list or adjacency matrix to represent which of the holes are next to each other.